# MVC3 unobtrusive validation with regex, always fails first time, then works

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

I'm trying to use the DataAnnotations RegularExpression attribute on a property of an item in a collection - A Field object has a collection for Formatter objects that in turn have a collection of Attributes with a Value property.

Inside my attribute view model class, I have:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+$", ErrorMessage = "That didn't do what you hoped it would do")]
public string Value { get; set; }
```

I have this in my view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor( x => x.Formatters[fmt].Attributes[att].Value )
```

and it produces this markup:

```
<input type="text" value=" " name="Formatters[1].Attributes[0].Value" data-val-regex-pattern="^\d+$" data-val-regex="That didn't do what you hoped it would do" data-val="true" >
```

All of that seems right, but the validation always fails the first time.  If I enter 23 into the textbox and tab out, it fires the validation event and tells me things didn't go like I'd hoped they would.  If I go back to the field and enter the exact same value, it works.  If I enter letters, it still fails as it should.

Anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong or what I can do to coerce the validation into behaving the first time around?  It seems to be related to the collections somehow because if I put the same validation attribute on a top level property, it works as it should.

Thanks!

Comment: Tracked it down to the line in the unobtrusive validation js file - "match = new RegExp(params).exec(value);"  RegExp.exec return null the first time and a value every time afterwards.

Comment: That's strange. I am unable to reproduce the issue. Could you please provide a narrowed down example of your view model, controller and view allowing to repro?

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to be isolated to my laptop at work.  I pulled down the code to a couple of other computers at home last night and everything works as expected.

I'm still not sure what's going on, but I don't think this is something the community can help resolve - unless someone wants to loan me a hammer.

Thanks for reading and thanks to Darin for trying to dig deeper.